# Get links from code using xpath without pgid and sid

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

While creating crawler for some website using scrapy I extracted links using xpath. But these links are some thing link this

> https://somedomain.com/someOtherUrl;sid=someSessionIdByServer;pgid=AgainSomeIdByServer

Now I don't understand why this sid and pgid are attached even when there is only url in the href. And the xpath code I used is some what like

```
//a/@href
```

Can I get just links. So, is there any way of getting only links with Scrapy.

I can just extract links using some python code. But I was curious to know if there is any way of doing things in the xpath or may be with setting in scrapy.

Comment: have you tried this? `//a/tokenize(@href, ';')[1]`

Comment: It gives invalid expression error when I use tokenize. 

Comment: “Now I don't understand why this sid and pgid are attached even when there is only url in the href.” Have you checked the actual code (not the DOM)? See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Comment: It's actually the server that adds this pgid and sid to the links.  I checked with raw html of the webpage and then I got idea about how there are getting to the links. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use Scrapy's `.re()` or `re_first()`:

```
response.xpath('//a/@href').re(r'^([^;]+)')
```

Comment: Thanks. But that is using python for getting data. I was looking for xpath way. I already know while using split method in python.

Answer (score 0):

use xpath `substring-before` function.

```
//a/substring-before(@href, ';')
```

since `scrapy` still not supporting `tokenize()` available in `xpath 2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Well with some time and efforts, I got to know some of the reasons, why this happens.So, I am answering my own question because it might help somebody else.

So, pgid (Process Group ID) and sid (Session ID) were added by the server itself. When I see through DOM on my browser. My browser already processed it and there I wasn't able to see sid and pgid on links. But when I fetch html using python then links do come url+sid+pgid format. The reason is given in  [this Scrapy Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom)

I used

```
element.xpath("/a/@href").split(";")[0]
```

to get just the url and remove sid and pgid from links.
It's not complete xpath solution. But that solved my problem.